# Bootstrap - how can I have a sticky header?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I would like to know how I can have a sticky header? I have been figuring out that for the whole day and still don't know how to do. Can anyone help me for that? What I want is that when I scroll down, the header will keep sticking on the top.

These are my codes. Thanks a lot!

```css
header {
  padding: 20px 0;
}

header .row,
footer .row {
  display: flex;    
  align-items: center;
}

header h1 {
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 0;
}

header nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end; 
}

header p {
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bo Kei Tuck Shop</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>   <!--Google Font API-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="about_us_main.css">    <!--CSS-->
        <script type='text/javascript' src='javascript/jquery-3.1.0.js'></script>   <!--jQuery-->
        <script type='text/javascript' src='javascript/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>  <!--jQuery-->
        <meta name="description" content="Free Web tutorials">  <!--meta description-->
        <meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,XML,JavaScript">    <!--meta keywords-->
        <meta name="content-language" content="en-US">
    </head>

    <body>
<!--header-->
        <header class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <h1 class="col-sm-4">Bo Kei Tuck Shop</h1>
                <nav class="col-sm-8">
                    <p>Hot Food</p>
                    <p>Cold Food</p>
                    <p>Snacks</p>
                    <p>Drinks</p>
                    <p>Contact Us</p>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>

      </body>
```

Comment: It's in the documentation - https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/ just add the class `navbar-fixed-top` to the `nav` tag.

Comment: @MoshFeu However, I have <nav class="col-sm-8"> in my nav tag, how i can stick the header together with the <h1 class="col-sm-4">Bo Kei Tuck Shop</h1>?

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your `div` and `nav` with another `div` and set it's class like in the docs (`navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top`).

Like this:

```css
body {
  height:1500px;  
}

header {
  padding: 20px 0;
}

header .row,
footer .row {
  display: flex;    
  align-items: center;
}

header h1 {
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 0;
}

header nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end; 
}

header p {
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bo Kei Tuck Shop</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>   <!--Google Font API-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="about_us_main.css">    <!--CSS-->
    <script type='text/javascript' src='javascript/jquery-3.1.0.js'></script>   <!--jQuery-->
    <script type='text/javascript' src='javascript/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>  <!--jQuery-->
    <meta name="description" content="Free Web tutorials">  <!--meta description-->
    <meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,XML,JavaScript">    <!--meta keywords-->
    <meta name="content-language" content="en-US">
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--header-->
    <header class="container">
      <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="row">
          <h1 class="col-sm-4">Bo Kei Tuck Shop</h1>
          <nav class="col-sm-8">
            <p>Hot Food</p>
            <p>Cold Food</p>
            <p>Snacks</p>
            <p>Drinks</p>
            <p>Contact Us</p>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>

  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<nav class="navbar  navbar-fixed-top">
```

[Click here for bootstrap proper navigation](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_fixed&stacked=h)

Comment: There is a way to create a nav follow the given link

Comment: However, I have <nav class="col-sm-8"> in my code already...how i can do that?

Comment: you can use like this <nav class="col-sm-8 navbar  navbar-fixed-top">

Comment: that class .navbar-fixed-top  make element fixed at top

Answer (score 0):

Have a look

```css
body{height:20000px}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bo Kei Tuck Shop</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>   <!--Google Font API-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="about_us_main.css">    <!--CSS-->
        <script type='text/javascript' src='javascript/jquery-3.1.0.js'></script>   <!--jQuery-->
        <script type='text/javascript' src='javascript/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>  <!--jQuery-->
        <meta name="description" content="Free Web tutorials">  <!--meta description-->
        <meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,XML,JavaScript">    <!--meta keywords-->
        <meta name="content-language" content="en-US">
    </head>

    <body>
<!--header-->
        <header class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <nav class="navbar  navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="navbar-header">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bo Kei Tuck Shop</a>
              </div>
                     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Hot Food</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Cold Food</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Snacks</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Drinks</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>

      </body>
```

Comment: Plz view this in full page mode